# A space of Lebesgue measure $0$ homeomorph to a space with non-null Lebesgue measure?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

**Question :**

Does there exist a space of Lebesgue measure $0$ homeomorph to a space with non-null Lebesgue measure ?

**My attempt :**

The problem is I have no idea whether it is true or false.
If I were to prove it true, I think I would look at Cantor spaces or similar.
If it was false, I would probably some uniform continuity on compact neighbourhoods.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: The $x$-axis has measure $0$ in the plane, but it is homeomorphic to the real line, which has measure $\infty$ in itself. But maybe you wanted both spaces to be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Comment: Do you know that all Cantor sets are homeomorphic to each other?

Comment: A "fat Cantor set" is homeomorphic to the Cantor set but has positive measure.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Why is true ? Do you have a proof of it ?

Comment: See [Homeomorphism between two Cantor sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429674/13130) *AND* [Homeomorphism between cantor sets one with measure 0 and one with positive measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/857757/13130) *AND* [The Cantor set is homeomorphic to infinite product of $\{0,1\}$ with itself - cylinder basis - and it topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69905/13130).