# continuous map from cantor set to another set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, cantor-set

> Let $C$ be the Cantor set with metric from $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ and $P = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \{0,\frac{1}{2^k}\}$ with metric from $(\ell_1, \lVert \cdot \rVert_1).$ Show that there exists a continuous bijection $f : C\to P.$

Every element of the Cantor set can be uniquely written in the form $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k}, a_k \in \{0,2\}\forall k.$ Then it suffices to show that the function $f : C\to P, f(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k}) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \{\frac{a_k/2}{2^k}\}$ is continuous. I think one could show it's sequentially continous, but I'm not really sure about the details. I can't really show that it's continuous because each of its components is continuous, as it has infinitely many components. And I'm finding it really hard to choose the right $\delta > 0$. Is there another function for which it's easier to prove continuity?

Comment: In fact $f$ is continuous if and only if $\pi_k\circ f$ is continuous for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$; this is a general property of the product topology, irrespective of the number of factors.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if you have an idea as to how to solve this problem, feel free to add an answer or another comment.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429674/homeomorphism-between-two-cantor-sets/429775#429775) and [this answer and comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69905/the-cantor-set-is-homeomorphic-to-infinite-product-of-0-1-with-itself-cy/69917#69917).